# Search In paths of the control flow graph

Tags: language-agnostic, ide, control-flow

Many times I'm having a problem with printing in function `foo`, and I want to look for all occurences of `Print` in code which is reachable in the Control Flow Graph from function `foo`. Or in all code in the paths between `foo` and `bar` (as I verified an assumption is true before I call `foo`, and false after I reach `bar`, so I want to find out what's happening in between).

Is there any tool that allows me to do that **easily**. I'm not going to compile all my C code with [CIL](http://cil.sourceforge.net/), and write an OCaml module to do search with the CFG. I want something that works with minimum hassle.

Eclipse CDT should be able to do that (you can calculate the CFG with `show function hiererchy`), but I didn't find something similar there.

I'm now targeting C/C++, but I'll be glad to hear about similar tools? I'm not sure [CQL](http://www.ndepend.com/CQL.htm) have a way to express that.